Converting the assertErrorMessages() into a string
Using dataflows to validate our incoming data via the Assert operation.
According to the documentation, I can retrieve a map of assert errors via the function assertErrorMessages().
I want to write these errors together with a some data (not all) into a csv file. So I use a derived column with function isError() to indicate if an error occurred. The error rows I conditionally split, use a select to only select a few columns and send them to a different sink.
The issue is that the error messages are in fact a map (kinda like an array) and are not written to the csv, the error message column remains null.
So trying to figure out how I can convert a map/array into a string. In the pipeline expression, we have the join() method which does the trick, however this method is not available in the derived column expression editor.
Any suggestions?

can you add screenshots of shat you have tried and error you are facing

To convert error messages to string you need to use values() expression so it will get only error messages from the output of assertErrorMessages() and the further unfold it using unfold() expression.
Follow Below approach:

After assert transformation add derived column transformation and extract values() from assertErrorMessages()

Data Preview for this:

Then Split the errored rows using isError() function in split transformation.

Then for errored rows use unfold() expression in derived column to further separate values array from assert error messages.


Final output:


Thank you very much for your feedback, it does kinda is a solution for our problems. However if we have multiple assert issues on the same row, the unfold creates a separate line for each assert type. Any idea how I can 'join' this separate by a comma or pipe?
